# Acceder a un button dentro de la fila de una tabla renderizada después de cargar el DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

Hola estoy usando ajax para poblar un `table`.

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ProductID</th>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>Category Name</th>
        <th>Unit Price</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="productList">
</tbody></table>
```

Al `tbody#productList` estoy agregándole la lista, el caso es que quiero acceder al `button (tbody#productList > tr > td > button)` para abrir una ventana modal de acuerdo a la fila y cargar la información en un formulario.

```
$("#productList").append(
'<tr id="productItem">' +
    '<td>' + this.ProductID + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + this.ProductName + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + this.CategoryName + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + this.UnitPrice + '</td>' +
    '<td class="hidden">' + this.CategoryID + '</td>' +
    '<td class="td">' +
    '<button type="button" id="btnEdit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></button>' +
    '<button type="button" id="btnDelete" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button>' +
    '</td>' +
'</tr>');
```

[image: Acceder al button dentro de la fila de una tabla renderizada después de cargar el DOM]

He logrado acceder al `tr` dando click a cada fila y me llena la información correspondiente, pero no es lo que quiero.

```
$('#productList').on("click", "tr", function () {
    $('#modal').modal('show');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

si van a ser varios renglones, te aconsejo que no manejes ids en tr ni en buttons, maneja clases

```
$('#productList').find('tr').find('.btn-edit').each(function(index) {
  $(this).on("click",function() {
    alert(index);
  });
});
```

aqui un ejemplo en jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/1cw3x40t/2/

Respondiendo a tu comentario abajo
de como acceder a los elementos del renglón para obtener información o para asignar información

html

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ProductID</th>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>Category Name</th>
        <th>Unit Price</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="productList">
</tbody></table>

<br/><br/>
<input id="nombreProdEnForm" value="" />
```

javascript

```
$("#productList").append(
  '<tr>' +
  '<td class="id-producto">100</td>' +
  '<td class="nombre-producto">x</td>' +
  '<td>x</td>' +
  '<td>x</td>' +
  '<td class="hidden">x</td>' +
  '<td class="td">' +
  '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-edit"><i 
class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>editar</button>' +
  '<button type="button"  class="btn btn-danger btn-delete"><i 
class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button>' +
  '</td>' +
  '</tr>'+
    '<tr>' +
  '<td class="id-producto">200</td>' +
  '<td class="nombre-producto">y</td>' +
  '<td>y</td>' +
  '<td>y</td>' +
  '<td class="hidden">y</td>' +
  '<td class="td">' +
  '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-edit"><i 
class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>editar</button>' +
 '<button type="button"  class="btn btn-danger btn-delete"><i 
class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button>' +
  '</td>' +
  '</tr>');


$('#productList').find('tr').find('.btn-edit').each(function(index) {
  $(this).on("click",function() {
  var valNomProdAEditar = 
$('#productList').find('tr').eq(index).find('.nombre-producto').html();  
  $('#nombreProdEnForm').val(valNomProdAEditar); 
  });
});
```

ejemplo obteniendo informacion de la tabla y mandandola a un formulario
https://jsfiddle.net/junmr/1cw3x40t/4/

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu comentario. Estoy usando el código pusiste y no ejecuta nada. ¿Sabes a que se debe? Pensé que seria por la versión de jquery, ya que .net incluye la 1.10.2, lo cambie por un cdn y no me ejecuta tampoco. He cambiado los id por class y aun no muestra nada. ¿Del modo que mencionas tambien se delega? La tabla se llena al cargar la pagina via ajax, asi que no existe hasta que terminar de cargar. Tampoco encuentra el <tr>, no me da una respuesta, peor aun el .btn-edit.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por tu comentario. Ya pude abrir la ventana modal accediendo a btn-edit, ¿pero como se hace para regresar al tr y cargar la informacion de las celdas en un formulario?  
$('#productList').on("click", "tr td .btn-edit", function () {
    var tr = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr');
    alert(tr.cells[0].textContent);
});

Comment: Hola, edite la respuesta